# use distance matrix with places and distance api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to use calculate distance API with auto place search and route API.
I have combined place search and route API but unable to combine it with distance matrix API. Can anyone give me and idea how to do it ?

here is my code for place search and route API, and its working corectly.

```
function initAutocomplete() {

    var origin_place_id = null;
    var destination_place_id = null;

    var travel_mode = google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING;

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      mapTypeControl: false,
      center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
      zoom: 13
    });

    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    var origin_input = document.getElementById('origin-input');
    var destination_input = document.getElementById('destination-input');


    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(origin_input);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(destination_input);


    var origin_autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(origin_input);
    origin_autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

    var destination_autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(destination_input);
    destination_autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

    // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
    // Autocomplete.

    function expandViewportToFitPlace(map, place) {
      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
        map.setZoom(17);
      }
    }

    origin_autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
      var place = origin_autocomplete.getPlace();
      if (!place.geometry) {
        window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
        return;
      }
      expandViewportToFitPlace(map, place);

      // If the place has a geometry, store its place ID and route if we have
      // the other place ID
      origin_place_id = place.place_id;
      route(origin_place_id, destination_place_id, travel_mode,
            directionsService, directionsDisplay);
    });

    destination_autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
      var place = destination_autocomplete.getPlace();
      if (!place.geometry) {
        window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
        return;
      }
      expandViewportToFitPlace(map, place);

      // If the place has a geometry, store its place ID and route if we have
      // the other place ID
      destination_place_id = place.place_id;
      route(origin_place_id, destination_place_id, travel_mode,
            directionsService, directionsDisplay);
    });

    function route(origin_place_id, destination_place_id, travel_mode,
                   directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
      if (!origin_place_id || !destination_place_id) {
        return;
      }
      directionsService.route({
        origin: {'placeId': origin_place_id},
        destination: {'placeId': destination_place_id},
        travelMode: travel_mode
      }, function(response, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        } else {
          window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
      });
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you need to use the distance matrix for?

Comment: to calculate the distance between two locations entered by the user like u say pickup and drop off @geocodezip

Comment: That data is available from the response to the directions service, you shouldn't need to use both.

Comment: wel, what i nee dis, user will ente rpickup and drop off location, and then the route will be drawn on the map from loc A to loc B, and distance between them will be shown on the website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned @geocodezip, you can retrieve the distance information from the directions service response.

The code snippet is the following:

```
directionsService.route({
    origin: {'placeId': origin_place_id},
    destination: {'placeId': destination_place_id},
    travelMode: travel_mode
}, function(response, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        //Get distance
        var d = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text;
        //TODO: show the distance at some div
        ....
    } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
});
```